# Clustering polygons by sum of values using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I would like to group polygons that (1) are contiguous and (2) when the combined values of field X >= Y.
Specifically I am grouping zipcodes that are connected. a group is when 1 or more zipcodes 'population' field equals 100,000.

Can someone suggest an existing ArcGIS function or python method for doing this?

---

I wrote a python algorithm to group the polygons using their respective neighbors as grouping members until threshold is met. it works nicely.

Comment: When you mean "group" do you mean dissolve the boundaries between them?

Comment: I mean assign neighboring polygons a unique #. They are neighboring and their total population = 50,000. then start over by moving onto the next polygon to build a new group. So the final result will be 100% of shapes (no dissolving) where each polygon belongs to a unique group. I imagine there will be ~300-400 groups for dataset of 1800 polygons.

Comment: There is no existing function to do this. That is partly because the problem is under-specified: in addition to the *constraints* you have imposed, you can optimize some *objective function,* such as achieving the most compact groups or the smallest number of groups, etc. Such optimization problems can often be solved with "black-box" procedures for *nonlinear constrained optimization.* They are also susceptible to approximate solution with simulated annealing or genetic algorithms.

Comment: @whuber thank you. this is what I am understanding. Though if I can add a concatenated list of polygon IDs that touch a given polygon, I might write a python script to go through each record and group them that way, adding their populations as it goes until X value is reached. thanks again

Comment: That (greedy algorithm) will give you *a* solution but in general it will not give a very good one. I can't be more specific because neither your question nor your proposed algorithm have been presented sufficiently clearly.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to do this? What higher-level problem does it solve? Grouping polygons until some condition is reached is dependent on their _order_ but how are you sorting them before grouping?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same objective in order to aggregate several municipalities according to their population to determine a higher level group. Cheers,
Carlos

Comment: This comment is to link this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/ While this question specifies ArcGIS and the other QGIS (etc.), an answer there explains this as Zone design and provides some references. Another answer provides a link to a third-party software that can accomplish the task and is independent of any specific GIS software.

Answer (score 1):

Create a field called "GROUP", type short.

Use Calculate Field on the new GROUP field:

Check Advanced

```
If [POPULATION] = 100000 then   'replace with >= or <= if you'd like to also include larger/smaller values
x = 1
else
x = 0
end if
```

GROUP = x

Now use the Dissolve tool.

Specify GROUP as the dissolve field.

Do NOT use Multipart Features.

Your result will group touching Zip Codes with values 0 or 1.  1 being areas meeting the criteria, 0 being areas that did not.

Comment: I want to give each group a unique #. so my dataset of 1800 polygons will be grouped into ~300 sets - where the sum of each set's population field >40,000 and <60,000.

Comment: You can use the OBJECTID's as the unique #.  The dissolve will output the grouped "sets" as new features.  To get >40000 and <60000, change the conditional to if [POPULATION] > 40000 AND [POPULATION] < 60000 then ...  You should have stated this in your original post, BTW...

Comment: This does not appear to solve the problem of grouping by *total* population within each group: it only examines populations of individual polygons.

Comment: For total population within groups, the POPULATION field can be added into the statistical fields parameters with a SUM operator when running the Dissolve field.  However, the more I reread these comments and original post, the more confused I get on what is ACTUALLY needed.