# Drawing boundaries between discrete features based on attribute values in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geometry, spatial-statistics, polygon-creation

There is a point feature class with a certain numeric attribute (let us say, populated places with population).

I wonder if there is, in ArcGIS, a way to draw polygons such that the sum of the attribute for all the points within each polygon does not exceed a certain value.

Does anyone know how this might be done?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: can you draw a picture? You can create Voronoi (Thiessen) polygons from your points but dissolving them such that the dissolved polygon has a specific value sounds a little more tricky. Would you be doing this with arcpy, model builder or ArcObjects? There isn't a native way to do this (that I know of).

Comment: I'll see if I can draw a picture soon. Yes, this is somewhat like Voronoi (Thiessen) polygons, except that there can be more than one point within each polygon, but the attribute's value for the points within a polygon may not add up to more than a certain figure. I will probably be doing this with ModelBuilder.

Comment: The basic problem is called the [Modifiable Areal Unit Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifiable_areal_unit_problem) (MAUP) and the task is known as Zone Design. The issue is that without some criteria other than just a total value, there are potentially an arbitrary number of possible solutions. You're dealing with points, but even if you converted each point to a polygon with Thiessen, combining the results leads to the same issue. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/ and its linked questions. It's like group/cluster analysis except you want value not proximity/groupsize.