# Tool to help us re-district?

Tags: polygon, google-maps, google-earth, point-in-polygon

I work for a mid-sized school district and we unfortunately have to close one of our school buildings.  That means that the neighborhoods who've been sending their children to the school that is closing will need to be redistributed among the remaining schools.

Currently, I have several kml files loaded into Google Earth, including one for each grade level of students attending the school to be closed, and one for each of the remaining schools containing a polygon representing it's boundary.  Visually, this is very informative, but it's not giving us what we really need.  Hopefully, there is another tool or feature out there that somebody can point me to.

I'm hoping to find a tool or website where I can manipulate the polygons representing the other schools' boundaries, pulling them into the neighborhoods of the closed school, and have it tell me how many placemarks or pins are then inside of each polygon.  I need to experiment with different configurations to try to evenly distribute both the overall number of students, but also the number of students at each grade level.

Does such a tool or web site exist? Unfortunately, I do not have the programming know-how or time to design something myself. Alternatively, perhaps somebody has another suggestion on how to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Sounds like QGIS will do what your require. http://qgis.org/en/site/ this tutorial might help explain how to http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: how about answers to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/dissolve-ploygons-in-qgis-or-grass-to-new-polygons-of-defined-population-sizes

Comment: Try [Arcgis districting](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/districting)

Comment: If this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/grouping-village-points-based-on-distance-and-population-size/123297#123297 sounds like what you need I might help in my spare time

Comment: "Alternatively, perhaps somebody has another suggestion on how to accomplish this goal?" hire somebody with both skillset and time to do the job?