# Can QGIS be used to define territories of equal population?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations

I was wondering whether the QGIS plugin Cmaps region generator can be used to define territories of equal population by splitting a file of small postal areas/polygons and then automatically building territories up with an equal size population?

Or are there other open source software that could do this?

Comment: If you know the population of each original polygon, but then you split them into smaller polygons, how will you know the population of the smaller polygons? You can't increase the resolution of existing data. You must start with the highest resolution of data that you need.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/dissolve-ploygons-in-qgis-or-grass-to-new-polygons-of-defined-population-sizes?rq=1

Comment: I've started with the smallest level of detail - the smallest polygons, and then these would need aggregating to create the larger territories with the defined population - if there is a plugin within QGIS to do this automatically?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. If you edit the original question to make it more clear what you're looking for, it's more likely that someone will answer it. Editing the question will also bump it up to the top of the "active questions" queue so more people will see it.

Comment: Have you tried the Cmaps plugin? People are more willing to help if they see that you've made an attempt to figure out your question.

Comment: Based on a previous post, I want to agglomerate small adjacent areas with tiny populations to their neighbours, to make up bigger areas with larger populations, with the population of these larger areas not exceeding a defined threshold.  I wonder whether this could be done automatically, using CMaps plugin, or using other software related to territory design/building?