# Merging neighbor polygons up to a specific area size in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, dissolve

I am looking into a way to merge neighboring polygons in Python into 10 groups so that each group has a specific area size. At the beginning I have 389 micro-zones stored in `outmulti` which I want to split into 10 neighboring (of equal size) zones. Assuming that the whole area of the 389 micro-zones is 19447273 m², I want to get 10 (being neighbors) bigger zones of size around 19447273/10 m² each.
My variable which stores the polygons is `outmulti` in the form:

| Type | Value |
| --- | --- |
| geometry.polygon.Polygon | Polygon object of shapely.geometry.polygon module |
| geometry.polygon.Polygon | Polygon object of shapely.geometry.polygon module |
| geometry.polygon.Polygon | Polygon object of shapely.geometry.polygon module |
| geometry.polygon.Polygon | Polygon object of shapely.geometry.polygon module |

I know I should use `unary_union` but it will group together into a single geometric feature of all my polygons (which I don't want). I do not know how to do that so that specify the neighboring polygons, as well as the limit of the area size of each of the 10 (bigger) zones.

Comment: Is this a [Bin Packing Problem][1]?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: @wingnut I wouldn't say is necessarily a bin packing problem.. 
I actually want to group the smaller micro-zones into group which all of them have almost the same area size. I guess, it would also work to merge all the 389 polygons to one and them divide them to 10 area-equal-size polygons. :/ Not sure though..

Comment: If the number of possibilities rises as n!, then you will have a challenge getting it to run fast. Could a clustering approach help? Randomly assign and then swap using a rule until the sums stabilise.

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/dissolving-ploygons-in-qgis-or-grass-to-new-polygons-of-defined-population-sizes help?